# Null checking formula returns no output

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I'm trying to display a 1 when both columns in a row are populated, and display a 0 otherwise. Since a formula field cannot refer to itself, I created two formula fields called `notnull` and `notnull output`

`Notnull` looks like this:

```
If NOT(isnull({Column1})) and NOT(isnull({Column2}))
then {@notnull output} = '1'
Else {@notnull output} = '0'
```

When I put this into my design, all the fields are blank. I want the output to look something like this table below. How can I fix this?

```
Column1    Column2    notnull output
 foo                        0
 bar         baz            1
             qux            0
 quux                       0
 gorge                      0
 foo         baz            1
 gorge       foo            1
```

Comment: Is this your entire formula? You recieve no errors?

Comment: No errors, just blank returns in each row for "notnull output".  "notnull output" is an entry formula field

Comment: Crystal doesn't use a double-equals sign for comparison, so you need to use `:=` instead of `=` for assignment. That's why your output's coming up blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `notnull` and rewrite `notnull output` to look like this:

```
IF ISNULL({Column1}) OR ISNULL({Column2})
THEN '0'
ELSE '1'
```

While it's true you can't put a formula inside itself, you don't need to! Just put the desired return values in the Then/Else clause and `notnull output` will display them by itself. This works with any return type; Booleans, characters, strings, dates, etc.